# Why does 'for x in <array>' not work as expected?

Tags: javascript

Many programming languages use the syntax of 'for x in ' in order to iterate over a list/array.

It also exists in JavaScript. However, the following code:

```
var arr = [5, 6, 9, 10];
for (var i in arr) {
    console.log(i);
}
```

outputs the indexes of the array 'arr', and not the elements of the array themselves (unlike other programming languages).

My question is why? Or what is the logic in JavaScript for this behavior?

Comment: That's just the ECMAScript prescribed behavior; so, it applies to more languages than JavaScript and it's certainly not limited to nodejs. If you'd like to enumerate values rather than property names, you're looking for [`for...of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) rather than [`for...in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in). This question is a duplicate of many, many others.

Comment: I'll make something up: iterating over an object will give its keys, and you can use those to get to the values. If it gave the values, you couldn't get the keys. For consistency, Arrays work the same way.

Comment: No, @Chris G, it doesn't work like that - `for...in` is only for objects and `arr` in the OP is an `Object`. The fact that it is also an array is coincidental in the example code.

Comment: @Guss Even if I hadn't literally started my comment with "I'll make something up", I don't see how anything you said contradicts anything I wrote. I haven't stated anywhere that for...in isn't only for Objects.

Comment: node.js is not a language. It's an engine which implements the JavaScript language.

Comment: @torazaburo nodejs isn't an engine either; it uses V8 (which _is_ an engine), so far as I know.

Comment: Semantics, semantics. My point is that it is not a language.

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is `for(i of arr)`. That will iterate the array and give `i` the value of each element of the array.

[Here's the documentation for it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of)

Alternatively, if you want to use `for(i in arr)` you can call the array element as `arr[i]`, as in that case `i` is simply the index.

Here is a snippet for all cases.

```js
var arr = [5, 6, 9, 10];
console.log('let i of arr, log i:');
for (let i of arr) {
  console.log(i);
}
console.log('let i in arr, log i:');
for (let i in arr) {
  console.log(i);
}
console.log('let i in arr, log arr[i]:');
for (let i in arr) {
  console.log(arr[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> My question is why? Or what is the logic in JavaScript for this behavior?

Roughly for the same reason that `+` means addition instead of subtraction. In other words, for the reason that that is what it is specified to mean.

Javascript has objects with properties and this feature was included (from very early in the history of JS--nearly two decades ago) as a way of iterating over those properties. It so happens that in the case of an array, the indices correspond to properties.